# how to solve the problem of network DHCP when I install Debian?

Tags: debian, dhcp

I am trying to install Debian 6, but I have a problem every time I pass through the network part, it says cannot recognize the DHCP and couldnt connect to the network, so, I tried manually to configure, it is connected to a network with a router, so, I assigned the IP and the Gateway but still, doesnt work, cannot connect to internet, the weird part is that I tried in other occasion and it worked, now I want to install it again and does not work! :-s what could it be?

Also when I try to install with a swap partition I get an error when formatting, if a create a partition for swap but without installing it it works... I set that as ext3 mount on / set as booteable.

Any idea of what these errors could be?
thanks.

Comment: So what's the reason that your dhcp doesn't work? Have you watched the network traffic with tcpdump or wireshark? And what ip/gateway did you specify for non-dhcp operation?

Comment: Is a DHCP server configured on your network in the first place?

Comment: Hi, the IP/Gateway I set was the ip of the router, at my case 192.168.1.1 , all other machines connected to that router get its IP, it works as DHCP, and assigns the IP its free, its not a server but the function is similar, however I set the IP as 192.168.1.40 (it was free) and still, nothing happened, but anyways, it should get its own IP from the router and work fine, I dont understand why this problem is appearing